# Most efficient way to add a constant to a column of an array in LabVIEW?

Tags: arrays, labview

I want to add a constant to the second column of an array.

I do this as shown below:

[image]

Where for illustration the values are as follows:

[image]

What is the most efficient way of adding a constant to an array column?

Comment: Your text is different than your picture. Do you want to add a single constant to a column of the 2D array (as shown by crossrulz) or do you want to add to arrays as shown in the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a question about efficiency you should supply number. For anything lower than a 1000 x 1000 2D array I can't measure the difference. Usually it is best to simply test it.

Here the code for testing (same answer as crossrulz)

[image]

With a 10000 x 10000 array option 2 becomes about 10 times faster.

One comment unless you are in a very high demanding situation, readability is usually preferred over efficiency. In my opinion option 2 is more readable since it has no for loop and the constant is presented as a constant instead of an array.

But you can get more efficient than that by using the In Place Element structure. The image below shows two different ways to add 5 to a column. The second one avoids making a memory copy of the entire array. Indexing out a column of an array with Index Array and then modifying it requires a shift of underlying memory format, even though the array is going to be put back in the Replace Array Subset. The In Place Element structure gives enough context to LabVIEW for it to recognize that the Add can be done without data copies.
[image: Add 5 to a column of an array, in 2 different ways]

Comment: So... I hate to be the bearer of bad news... but that Index Array/Replace Array sequence? That's really inefficient. That's a full data copy of the array. Turn on Tools >> Profile >> Show Buffer Allocations and you can see -- the Add primitive will do a whole buffer allocation (and the CH window shows subarray on left, non-subarray on right of Add). Use the In Place Element structure instead. There's a bit more wiring (because you have to make the element access explicit) but the code execution is WAAAAAAY more efficient.

Comment: I should clarify my previous comment: the subarray and buffer alloc occurs when you index a *row*. When indexing a column, LV always makes a copy. Quirk of memory layout. NI should really investigate that more. Seems like there could be improvements made.

Comment: @srm Thanks for your very extensive addition. I already had the feeling LV would probably supply more memory efficient structures but I did not have the time to look into it. Nice job.

Comment: `In Place Element structure` Thanks!  That was what I was trying to remember!!

Answer (score 3):

Index Array to get the second column, add your constant, and then Replace Array Subset to replace the second column.
[image]

Comment: Is that actually more efficient?  Is the add still looping through the column array?

Comment: That is a very hard question to answer. On low level and on matrix algorithms usually a lot of compiler optimisation is happening. Sometimes obvious and sometimes not so obvious. This is a whole field in itself where even the way of storing a matrix and the processor architecture come into play. That is why it is usually best to simply test the response on the intended system.